# Splitting a vector of lists of factors into dataframe with column for each factor level

Tags: r

I have received data like:

```
tree_uses <- c("Food Fuel Land_benefits Medicines","Food","Food","Food Fuel","Food Fuel","Food")
```

The factors for each obs split on the white space. I need to convert this into a df with 1 row for each obs and 1 col per "real" factor level.

So for the above data it would look as follow:

```
ID   Food   Fuel  Land_benefits  Medicines ....
1      1      1        1             1
2      1      0        0             0
3      1      0        0             0
4      1      1        0             0
5      1      1        0             0
6      1      0        0             0
...
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example: `dput(trees$tree_uses[1:6])`

Answer (score 1):

Found this works:

```
split_factor_cols <- function(x) {
    temp1 <- strsplit(as.character(x)," ")
    factor_names <- unique(unlist(temp1))
    zz <- length(factor_names)
    df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=length(x),ncol=zz))
    names(df) <- factor_names

    for(i in 1:zz) {
        df[,i] <- unlist(lapply(temp1,function(y) sum(charmatch(factor_names[i],x=y),na.rm=T)))
    }
return(df)
}
```

Perhaps someone knows a convenient function?

Comment: Provide reproducible example data, I am guessing you are looking for "convert factor to binary columns". `dput(trees$tree_uses[1:6])`

Comment: Hope the data are now in the correct format. Yes I want binary colomns, but my data have multiple factor levels for each observation. So the first step is to split the data into separate factor columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using *tm* package:

```
library(tm)

d <- VCorpus(VectorSource(tree_uses))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(d)

# inspect(dtm)

as.matrix(dtm)
#     Terms
# Docs food fuel land_benefits medicines
#    1    1    1             1         1
#    2    1    0             0         0
#    3    1    0             0         0
#    4    1    1             0         0
#    5    1    1             0         0
#    6    1    0             0         0
```